# Connections between Clifford algebra and polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

The multi-vector idea in Clifford algebra really reminds me of polynomial multiplication.

Can we treat every basic vector as a degree one polynomial, and multi-vectors as simply high-degree polynomials?

Is there any research trying to bridge the gaps between those two branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are constructed as important quotients of the tensor algebra over a vector space $V$. The polynomials are heavily linked to the symmetric algebra (via a duality), which is basically "the tensor algebra where you've injected commutativity". The exterior algebra is "the tensor algebra into which you've injected anticommutativity"; a Clifford algebra is a quantization of the exterior algebra. There are interesting morphisms between all algebras of this bunch.

The property (analogy) I think that you're noticing is that of a graded (or more generally filtered) algebra. As for their multiplication, it is what we call a discrete convolution (bilinear/distributive multiplication): that's because they're all quotients of the tensor algebra which is the "most general" way of defining a bilinear multiplication over vectors.

You may also want to look at Weyl algebras, which are quantizations of the symmetric algebra.